# Type for an entity with optional fetchable relations

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a REST API that can optionally fetch relations, if I ask it to do so: for example, if I call `GET /payment-request` I receive this payload (simplified for the sake of clarity):

```json
[
  {
    "id": "01FBPR3K0RYBCRGCBWEC2AK30P",
    "payer": "01FBRKNQRP74VBWW67N4BTH40B",
    "payee": "01FB460C0FC6BSTK835VF5735J",
    "dueDate": "2021-07-31",
    "amount": 99988
  }
]
```

But if I call `GET /payment-request?fetch=payee` I get

```json
[
  {
    "id": "01FBPR3K0RYBCRGCBWEC2AK30P",
    "payer": "01FBRKNQRP74VBWW67N4BTH40B",
    "payee": {
      "id": "01FB460C0FC6BSTK835VF5735J",
      "fullName": "John Doe",
      "email": "john@test.com"
    },
    "dueDate": "2021-07-31",
    "amount": 99988
  }
]
```

I can also fetch multiple relations at the same time, like `GET /payment-request?fetch=payer,payee`. Both `payer` and `payee` are not nullable, but I have also other entities that have a more lax constraints. Basically every relation could be nullable, and could point to a different type.

At the moment the types that I'm using on the frontend are pretty simple, but It feels quite clumsy and I need to do a good number of type checks in my code:

```js
type BusinessEntity = {
    id: string;
    fullName: string;
    email: string;
};

type PaymentRequest = {
    id: string;
    payer: string | BusinessEntity;
    payee: string | BusinessEntity;
    dueDate: string;
    amount: number;
};
```

Today I've tried to put up some kind of generic to describe optional fetches, but it works only with a single fetch required:

```js
type PaymentRequest<Fetched extends ('payer' | 'payee')[]> = {
    id: string;
    payer: Fetched extends ['payer'] ? BusinessEntity : string;
    payee: Fetched extends ['payee'] ? BusinessEntity : string;
    dueDate: string;
    amount: number;
};
```

In this way I can do something, but not everything:

```js
let plain : PaymentRequest<[]>;                  // OK: both payed and payee are string
let single : PaymentRequest<['payer']>;          // OK: payer is a BusinessEntity, payee is a string
let double : PaymentRequest<['payer', 'payee']>; // WRONG: both payer and payee are string again
```

I have no clue about how to check if an "array generic type" contains a single value. Anyone has a piece of advice for me?

## Final Solution

I've took captain-yossarian's solution and I've worked on a little further to simplify it:

```js
type PaymentRequest<Fetched extends 'payer'|'payee'|''=''> = {
    id: string;
    payer: 'payer' extends Fetched ? BusinessEntity : string;
    payee: 'payee' extends Fetched ? BusinessEntity : string;
    dueDate: string;
    amount: number;
};
```

Now the syntax is more concise, and I can just ignore the generic when I'm dealing with the standard output:

```js
let plain : PaymentRequest;                   // OK: both payed and payee are string
let single : PaymentRequest<'payer'>;         // OK: payer is a BusinessEntity, payee is a string
let double : PaymentRequest<'payer'|'payee'>; // OK: both payer and payee are BusinessEntity
```

Comment: What states are allowed? I mean if `payer` is string then `payee` should be also string ? Could you please provide all combination of allowed values

Comment: Edited the OP. In this specific case both payer and payee are not nullable, but it works differently for other entities in the project. Some have also relations with other types: as I wrote, this is a simplified payload: in reality the PaymentRequest has also a `contract` field, that is a nullable reference to another type Contract.

Comment: Also: I can call the API with wathever combination of fetches: none, payer, payee, or both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```js
type BusinessEntity = {
  id: string;
  fullName: string;
  email: string;
};

type CustomPaymentRequest<Fetched extends ('payer' | 'payee')[]> = {
  id: string;
  payer: 'payer' extends Fetched[number] ? BusinessEntity : string;
  payee: 'payee' extends Fetched[number] ? BusinessEntity : string;
  dueDate: string;
  amount: number;
};

let plain: CustomPaymentRequest<[]>;
let single: CustomPaymentRequest<['payer']>;
let double: CustomPaymentRequest<['payer', 'payee']>;

type O = CustomPaymentRequest<['payer']>['payee'] // string
type OO = CustomPaymentRequest<['payee']>['payee'] // BusinessEntity
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgZwJYDsIIQURcJooC8UA3gFBRRIAmAXFAsAE6oDmA3OVAGZwA2vAOQCGAWwh0GzFO04QRQpLwlNWHAL4dSoSFADCiYAHsRABSEgxOAEoQAjnHTAAPADEIwAMYALCFSgQAD2AIFCoEKAAKAHIwcwhGKKgAHygYuIgogEoAbQBdAD5CEk5qZSkZCliQeLo06oT-IJCwqDdPHypslDgRACN43KgAflhEVHQsHDwQKDLVTiqIcVTFjMbg0PC2718unv7GQZH4ZDQMbFx8OekOCioHABEhYOuKqFFDOBw6br749U0vHcUDAvAUKDo%20gYxjMFhCwBs9kcTjy%20Q4QOA9FYQMhBhh5ksCLsDgYKLq8SiBXRwKon16OL0eNMBPhiJJzmy5ISABoVulKWjSFpwNAAPJFKFGZlw6zE5GcxYJAoK-mDAD0avoKmkwp0ovFREl%20JlRKRpJV1QyyvJVqgGtGpwmF2mQA)

Comment: I knew I was on the good path! It works like a charm, thank you!